# How to use Laravel 8 Auth with Bootstrap/React, without Laravel UI?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Since Laravel UI started recommending Laravel Breeze and Jetstream packages then what is the best way to use Laravel Authentication with any frontend we need such as Bootstrap or React?

I don't need Livewire or Inertia at the moment but these are included in the above packages by default. Should I use **Fortify** or is there any other simple method to get the default Laravel Auth functionalities?

Comment: Authentication in laravel is included in the base framework. You don't need any of these libraries. That being said these libraries are convenience so pick one that does the things you want so you don't need to implement them yourself. From the sounds of it Fortify would be helpful in your case since it includes the functionality you need

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend using [passport](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport) or [sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum).

**Official documentation :**

Before getting started, you may wish to determine if your application would be better served by Laravel Passport or Laravel Sanctum. If your application absolutely needs to support OAuth2, then you should use Laravel Passport.

However, if you are attempting to authenticate a single-page application, mobile application, or issue API tokens, you should use Laravel Sanctum. Laravel Sanctum does not support OAuth2; however, it provides a much simpler API authentication development experience.